# How to enable cache for Satis composer registry in Artifactory

Tags: composer-php, artifactory, satis

I have a problem setting up internal composer registry in artifactory. For a long time we are using satis as a registry for php packages, but currently we slowly moving to artifactory for other languages and want same for php.

I've configured composer remote registry for packagist.org and it works well (expect I don't understand why I need to set github.com as git provider and what will be if it gitlab or something).

Btw I configured one more registry for internal packages, in Registry URL I set our satis url (https://packagist.internal). Now i can install packages from it, but it does not cache files in artifactory and serve it directly from our private repository.

Looks like this:

```bash
$ composer i -vvv
...
Downloading https://artifacts.plesk.tech/artifactory/api/composer/composer-internal/packages.json
...
Installs: os/pear:1.0.4
  - Downloading os/pear (1.0.4)
Downloading https://packagist.internal/dist/os/pear/os-pear-1.0.4-8d8196.zip
```

As you can see, it download metadata from artifactory, but artifacts directly from satis, besides I enabled caching in advanced > other > Store Artifacts Locally. In Satis access log I only see requests to json files from artifactory, but not to zip. Also it for some reason trying to request these urls:

```
GET /api/system/version/service HTTP/1.1" 404 821 "-" "Artifactory/7.39.4 73904900
GET /api/system/version HTTP/1.1" 404 821 "-" "Artifactory/7.39.4 73904900
```

For packagist.org work as expected:

```bash
Installs: psr/log:3.0.0
  - Downloading psr/log (3.0.0)
Downloading https://artifacts.plesk.tech/artifactory/api/composer/composer-general-remote/vcs-dists/zip/php-fig/log/fe5ea303b0887d5caefd3d431c3e61ad47037001
[200] https://artifacts.plesk.tech/artifactory/api/composer/composer-general-remote/vcs-dists/zip/php-fig/log/fe5ea303b0887d5caefd3d431c3e61ad47037001
```